# Swiping UIImageView ofscreen

Tags: animation, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIImageView that needs to be able to be panned all over the view, pinched and rotated, but the imageView needs to change picture on a swipe movement as well. Any idea on how to accomplish this? I have added a UISwipeGestureRecognizer but that will change the picture on any swipe movement. Ideal would be for me to make the picture animate away and the new one on to the screen once the user drags it of the screen or when it's not visible on the screen for more than 50%. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what a [UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) was made for. Simply add all your `UIImageView`'s to the `UIScrollView`, position them in the right order, and set `.paging = YES`. Make sure you also set the correct `contentSize`, or the `UIScrollView` won't scroll at all!

Also, check out the [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate) methods for how to configure the `UIScrollView` for zooming. You may need to put the `UIImageView`'s in their own `UIScrollView` which will enable zooming for that specific `UIImageView`, but this depends on your needs.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: Doing that will make me loose the animations of moving a card away + the random rotation angle every image has.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it. Using a scrollview was indeed the solution to this, and I can keep the random rotation angle (although images will overlap a little bit) + the gestures. Thanks for your help!